# How can I fix this jquery issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do have a `input['text']` field to insert date and also have a `dropdown` for select category.

When changing the date input field I want to make the page reload with attaching date and category values in the URL.

**NOTE:** Here I want to attach category value if it is not empty.

This is how I tried it. But it doesn't work for me.

```
$("#date").change(function() {
  var c = $("#category").val();
  var d = $(this).val();
  if(c.length === 0 ) { 
    var cat = "$cat="+c; 
  } else {
    var cat; 
  }

  location.href="?p=attendance&todate="+d.add(cat);
})
```

This is the output, when category ID is not empty.

```
?p=attendance&todate=2016-08-04undefined
```

Can anybody help me to fix my problem? 
Thank you.

Comment: This issue would probably be nonexistent, if you simply submitted the form the normal way, instead of trying to manipulate the URL yourself.

Comment: @CBroe, I have to display other fields according to this date and category selection. Thats why I repress the page...

Comment: What does this have to do with anything? Just submit the form when the date field change event fires – then it will put the current field values into the URL _automatically_, because that’s how GET forms work.

Comment: Why reload the page? Why not just update the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this approach. Put only what you have.

```
$("#date").change(function() { 
    var url = ''; 
    var c = $("#category").val(); 
    var d = $(this).val(); 
    if(c.trim().length) { url+='&cat='+c } 
    if(d.trim().length) { url+='&todate='+d } 
    location.href="?p=attendance"+url; 
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if category is empty, then I can get `?p=attendance&todate=2016-08-04&cat=`. Can you tell me how to remove `&cat=` if category is empty.

Comment: @user3733831 then just check c.trim().length. See the edited answer.